# Django localisation - thousand separator

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

In settings.py I have :

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'    
USE_I18N = True    
USE_L10N = True    
USE_TZ = True
```

And in the django template I'm trying to do next :

```
{% load l10n %}
.....
.....
<div>{{ price|floatformat:0|localize }}</div>
```

But the number that I see is still without separator : **9080**.

I tried to enable thousand_separator as follows :

```
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = '.'
```

But then is the separator (*not dot, but comma*) added to all id's that my site uses. Thus if I send an `id=9800` to my view I get `9,800` and I get an error.

I have read that I can use `{{ value|unlocalize }}` or `{{ value|safe }}`, but I do not want to do that for all my vars. Is there any better way to do that?

Can I use `thousand_separator` only in one template for only one var? Thus, something like :

```
{% load l10n %}
.....
.....
<div>{{ price|floatformat:0|localize }}</div>
```